# Is there a more elegant javascript solution?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

Working on a role checking function.  I store plain text user roles in the DB since it's easier to understand.  I convert my userRole to the index value of the $roles array, do the same for neededRole and then check to see if the userRole value is less than the neededRoleValue.  It works, but seems like there's a cleaner way to do it. Am I wrong or can I accomplish the same thing in less code?

```
roleCheck = function(){
    var userRole = 'admin'; 
    var reqRole = 'producer'
    var $roles = ['super', 'admin', 'producer', 'resource','client'];
    var userRoleValue;
    var reqRoleValue;

    _.each($roles, function(v, i){
        if(v===userRole){
            userRoleValue = i;
        }
    })

    _.each($roles, function(v, i){
        if(v===reqRole){
            reqRoleValue = i;
        }
    })
    if(userRoleValue<=reqRoleValue){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: @EvanKnowles On an array, [where index order is important](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in#Array_iteration_and_for...in)?

Comment: I'm just asking cause it seems like they're probably is a cleaner way.

Comment: This seems like a better fit for codereview. Whilst this function works according to your requirements in your post, I do wonder what you are hoping to achieve with this function. This doesn't seem like an effective way of role checking at all.

Comment: I don't see why you can't just check whether or not a user has X role. `function roleCheck(user, expectedRole) { return _.contains(user.roles, expectedRole); }` would work fine here. You don't need to store all of the roles here nor iterate over them or check if one is greater than another. You just need to check whether or a user, whose roles are stored in `user.roles`, has `expectedRole`.

Comment: For the record OP posted a comment asking for alternatives before I posted the above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simplify this with [`.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf).

<kbd>[**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/bujare/2/edit?js,console)</kbd>

```
roleCheck = function (){
  var userRole = 'admin',
      reqRole = 'producer',
      roles = ['super', 'admin', 'producer', 'resource','client'];


  return (roles.indexOf(userRole) <= roles.indexOf(reqRole));
}
```